Was versteht man unter „Kausal" bei „TeKaMoLo"?
Ich bin dabei, „TeKaMoLo" zu wiederholen, d.h., wie man die Satzteile in einem Satz ordnet.  Dass Buch, mit dem ich arbeite, meint, dass Phrasen wie

ohne Grund


trotz des Regens

und

zur Befriedigung der touristischen Bedürfnisse

als „kausal" betrachtet werden sollen. (Ich weiß, das viel vom Kontext abhängt, aber die ersten zwei waren einfach zu klassifizieren, weiteren Kontext gibt es nicht.)
In Hinsicht auf die die letzte Phrase, soll man „Zweck" auch als „kausal" verstehen?  D.h., sind Phrasen, die einen Antrieb ausdrücken, als kausal zu verstehen, nicht nur Phrasen die ausführlich eine Ursache geben?  Das begreife ich.
Aber „trotz des Regens" und „ohne Grund" sehe ich nicht als „kausal" an.  Ich würde eher an „modal" denken: wir haben das ohne Grund gemacht - wie haben wir das gemacht,nicht warum.
Kann man das ein bisschen ausführlicher erklären?

lat. causa = "Ursache". "ohne Ursache" ist doch auch eine kausale Aussage, so wie "dunkel" auch eine Aussage über "Helligkeit" ist?

Tu Dir einen Gefallen - und vergiß, daß es diesen "TeKaMoLo"-Unsinn gibt - denn in Wahrheit gibt es diese Regel nicht, es gibt nur englische Muttersprachler, die glauben, daß Deutsch eine Art süd-angelsächsischer Dialekt ist. Vergiß "TekaMolo", vergiß "direkte" und "indirekte" Objekte und sonstige Entlehnungen aus der englischen Grammatik.

@bakunin  Das würde ich gerne machen! :-)  Ich habe den anderen Tag mit einer Muttlersprachlerin gesprochen, und natürlich hatte sie keine Ahnung von dieser TeKaMoLo-Regel.  Sie stellt die Satzteile nur so, dass sie ihr gut „klingen".  Aber was würdest du dann den Nicht-Muttersprachlern empfehlen, um die richtige Reihenfolge von Satzteilen zu bestimmen?

@bakunin "TeKaMoLo" ist keine "Entlehnung aus der englischen Grammatik". Das wäre eher "MoLoTeKa". Es ist eine Erfindung der DaF-Lehrer.

@tofro: die "Entlehnungen" bezogen sich mehr auf die direkten und indirekten Objekte und die Idee, daß es eine einzige "richtige" Reihenfolge der Satzglieder geben könnte - was auf Englisch so ist, auf Deutsch aber nicht (und in anderen, die Flektion markierenden Sprachen, zB Latein, auch nicht).

"TeKaMoLo" ist keine "Regel". Sondern eher eine "(sehr) zurückhaltende Empfehlung". Muss also nicht, und schon gar nicht blind, befolgt werden.
Deutsche Muttersprachler kennen, wie du erfahren hast, diese "Regel" überhaupt nicht, sie setzen adverbiale Ergänzungen nach Lust und Laune (oder eher so, wie sie die Betonung haben wollen, dabei kommt das wichtigste normalerweise zuerst).

Ich gehe wegen des Regens heute nicht aus.

(mir ist der kausale Aspekt wichtig)

Ich gehe heute wegen des Regens nicht aus

(der temporale Aspekt ist wichtig)
Aber auch das betont den temporalen Aspekt:

Ich gehe wegen des Regens nicht aus heute

TeKaMoLo soll dich nur davor bewahren, eher ungebräuchliche Reihenfolgen zu verwenden - ganz beliebig ist die Reihenfolge nämlich nicht, manche Adverbiale wie z.B. "immer" "passen" für einen Muttersprachler z.B. nur an bestimmte Stellen (möglichst links aber nicht an den Anfang und fast nie ans Ende des Satzes) - Aber das hängt eher vom Adverbial ab als von TeKaMoLo, was aber eine wesentlich schwieriger zu erfassende Regel wäre.
Und warum "ohne Grund" kausal ist? Auch die Abwesenheit eines Grundes (lat. "Causa" - Ursache) ist doch "kausal". Und ja, in diesem Sinne ist auch der "Zweck" eine "Ursache", und "trotz des Regens" ist eben das Gegenteil von "wegen des Regens", was eben auf die "Abwesenheit eines Grundes" oder einen "Gegengrund" hinweist. Modal sind beide jedenfalls nicht - denn sie werden nicht mit "wie" erfragt. Eine Frage "warum nicht" ist eben auch eine Frage nach der Kausalität.
Aber, wie gesagt: (Fast) vollkommen egal.

Da wo du sagst "ist wichtig" geht es eigentlich darum "ist bekannt / gegeben". ZB: "Ich gehe heute wegen des Regens nicht raus" -- d.h. vermutlich wurde bereits davon gesprochen, was man heute machen will, in diesem Fall ist "heute" auch unbetont. Ich finde, das ist das Gegenteil von "wichtig". Anders "Ich gehe wegen des Regens heute nicht raus" -- d.h. heute nicht, aber an anderen Tagen eher. Hier, wo das das Adverb später im Satz kommt, ist es eher Fokus bzw. neue Information. Also wichtiger.

@tofro Danke!  Ja, da hast du Recht.  Es stimmt, dass ich nie an so eine Regel gedacht habe, als ich im deutschsprachigen Raum gewohnt habe (ich weiß nicht, ob ich früher von ihr je gehört habe).  Aber ich finde, dass ich manchmal Fehler bei der Reihenfolge begehe (das wird mir von Muttersprachlern gesagt).  Also bin ich dabei, diese Regel (wieder?) zu lernen.  Es kommt mir alles ein bisschen künstlich vor, wenn man daran denkt, dass die deutsche Sprache sehr flexibel ist.  Aber dann hat man das Problem: wie baut man die Sätze 100% richtig auf, ohne an Regeln du denken?

Nun, ich denke, es gibt zwei verschiedene Möglichkeiten: 1. Man lernt solche (relativ sinnlosen) Regeln wie TeKaMoLo und versteht sie, als das, was sie sind - Richtschnuren, keine in Stein gemeißelten Gesetze, oder 2. mit sehr, sehr viel Übung und Praxis - dann funktioniert es auch ohne Regeln automatisch. Man darf als Nicht-Muttersprachler durchaus auch mal einen Fehler machen.
